# recommendations on turkish-->ipa dictionary

Tags: ipa, turkish

Preferably a research-quality text. It doesn't need to be edited in English necessarily; and can be based on any dialect or standardization since the republics founding.

I'm not a native speaker, so I wouldn't trust my own interpretation of the phonemes for transcribing. And I don't consider the Turkish-Latin script to be sufficient for my purposes. (For instance, I would like the distinction between *l* and velarized *ɫ* for neighboring front/back vowels [1](https://cohenpr-xpf.github.io/XPF/conv_resources/info/tr.html).) Thx!

Answer (score 2):

You could download the data from [TELL](https://linguistics.berkeley.edu/TELL/). Elicit.db.txt and Elicit2.db.txt have IPA transcriptions of paradigms, and does bother with l ~ ɫ though not e ~ ɛ. The Turkish government has a [site with recordings](https://sozluk.gov.tr/) for very many words, but you would have to do your own transcription.